# iOS: MKAnnotationViews are very slow to appear

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mapkit

I am adding 54 annotations to an MKMapView in a loop like this:

```
for (Item *item in items) {

    [mapView addAnnotation:item];       

}
```

I am logging when this completes and it never takes long, but there is a very long delay before the annotations appear on my map view. What is going on? How can I get the annotations to appear faster?

**Update:** the data set I am using is not small and I am holding it entirely in memory. I have noticed the occasional level 1 or 2 memory warning. Could this impact MKMapView performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that code for adding annotations. The problem is probably somewhere else. Maybe you're getting the annotations from a web service. Maybe your annotation view objects are very large or complex.

If you want to try a different approach, use `addAnnotations:` to add all annotations at once, but I don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: Hi Nevan, the annotations do come from a webservice but this completes long before I add them to the map. I've put an nslog at the end of my addAnnotation loop method and I've put another nslog in mapView:viewForAnnotation: .. I've found that this latter method isn't called until I touch the map and move it?? What's going on here?

Comment: Something wrong there. You could look at `–mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` too. I'd suggest making a test project and adding some annotations to a more simple mapview, then building it back up so you can find the problem.